# Is it a viable method to load a program and run it from memory in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, reflection

I'm creating a wrapper for WkHtmlToPdf. This executable parses html and returns a pdf document as the name suggests.

You call this as follows: wkHtmlToPdf.exe www.example.com "C:\Results\Result.pdf".

The executable also comes with a few dlls.

Is there an easy solution to load the .exe into memory and call it?

Currently the code I wrote takes the .exe and the .dlls as resources, saves them to the Temp directory and calls them via command line. This current method is working nicely, but the step of saving them to the temp directory to call them sounds unnecessary. Surely there is a something like SomeReflectionMethod.Invoke(Resources.wkHtmlToPdf.exe, "www.example.com \"C:\Results\Result.pdf\"").

I have found similar questions, but am finding it difficult seeing the similarities between my specific question (and henceforth the accuracy of the provided answer).

I also have run into a few scary solutions as defined [here](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/).

Comment: [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Comment: Native DLL's cannot be loaded from memory (at least not for p/invoke).

Comment: Hello Robert, I would like to use Process.Start but am not sure how to call an in memory executable and allow it to see the .dlls

Comment: Hello VcsJones. There was no real solution provided, just saying it would be difficult to recurse through the dll dependencies that have dll dependencies. I only have 5 dlls and one .exe.

Comment: Storing DLLs into an EXE is very common.  The EXE is normally called setup.exe, you no doubt used one before.  Most every Windows user expects one.

Comment: I would use ILMerge and merge the dll's with the .exe. Could you possibly provide an answer on how to call this new merged .exe in memory though?